# Prove that for any real number the inequality is true: $x^4-x^3+5x^2 > 3x - 6$

Tags: polynomials

Prove that for any real number the inequality is true:

$x^4-x^3+5x^2 > 3x - 6$

The only way I could do this is to transform this inequality to:

$x^4-x^3+5x^2-3x+6> 0$

and then sketch the graph. But the problem is that probably I'm not able to find derivative of left side of the inequality manually. However, I don't think this is the best way to prove that. I suppose I should transform this to a better form but I don't know how.

Comment: Did you try completing the square? It might help.

Comment: The polynomial factors very nicely, two quadratics

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Separating the even and odd terms we need to show
$x^4+5x^2+6 > x^3+3x$ . That is $(x^2+2)(x^2+3)> (x^3+3x)$.
As $x^2+3$ is always positive, that factor can be cancelled on both sides, and we need to show
$(x^2+2)> (x+1)$. This is equivalent to showing $(x^2+1)>x$. For $x<0$, and $x>1$ this inequality is trivial. For $x\in[0,1]$ not hard.

Comment: Why not $x^2+2>x \iff x^2 - x + 2 > 0$? Then discriminant is less than 0 so this inequality is true for $x \in R$.

Comment: @tdudzik: definitely that is a simpler argument.

Answer (score 6):

We have:
$$4(x^4-x^3+5x^2-3x+6)=(x^2+3)((2x-1)^2+7)$$

Comment: Great, but how would I come up with this idea?

Comment: If you observe the polynomial you can see:$$x^4-x^3+5x^2-3x+6=x^4-x^3+2x^2+3x^2-3x+6=x^2(x^2-x+2)+3(x^2-x+2)$$

Comment: Ok, now I see it. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Factoring we get $$x^2(x^2-x+5)>3(x-2).$$ Since $P(x)=x^2-2x+5$ has a negative discriminant, it is always positive, thus the LHS is non-negative, becoming zero only when $x^2$ does, namely $x=0$. Hence the inequality is trivial for $x\le2$. For $2<x<3$ we have $$x^2(x^2-x+5)>28>9>3(x-2)$$ and finally for $x\ge3$ $$x^2(x^2-x+5)>x^2\ge3x>3(x-2).$$